# Why does program continue after exit?

Tags: php, php-8

Why is PHP8 not exiting after exit? We are testing our codeigniter3-based server upgrade to php8 and getting strange errors even after we fixed all our unit-tests (and other obvious compatibility errors).

```
<?php

function e() {
    echo "in e\n"; 
    exit;
}


echo "before e\n";
e();
echo "after e\n";
```

Running it in php8:

```
$ php test.php 
before e
in e
after e   <--- WTH
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5569b453fc3482b2c81b474e34b423ca489b31a4

Comment: I tried this on debian 11 ```$ php -v
PHP 8.0.11 (cli) (built: Sep 23 2021 22:04:05) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.11, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: This site which runs in every released version of PHP doesn't reproduce this either: https://3v4l.org/AeY0F I also tested on a local WSL Ubuntu instance with PHP v8.0.11, and can't reproduce it there either. My guess is that you have a debugging or monitoring which is "catching" the exit and misbehaving; try running the test script on the command line with the `-n` flag to PHP, which stops any config files, and therefore any extensions, loading.

Comment: You probably have the uopz extension installed.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.. it's caused by the uopz extension package. Removed the package and it worked as expected.

Comment: this package is not installed still causing issue.